# creating a larger matrix from smaller matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, text-files

I have a series of text files in a folder called "Disintegration T1" which look like this:

```
> 1.txt
0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   0
> 2.txt
0   1   1   0   1
0   0   1   1   1
1   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0   1
> 3.txt
0   1   1   1
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
```

The files are all either 4X4 or 5X5.  They must be read in as matrices, as the data is for social network analyses.  My goal is to automate the process of putting these matrices into a larger matrix, so that these matrices are directly diagonal to each other, and 0s inputted in the blank spaces within the larger matrix.  In this case the final result would look like:

```
> mega_matrix
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Thank you!

Comment: this is called a *block diagonal* matrix.  See `Matrix::bdiag` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `bdiag` from the Matrix package:

```
library(Matrix)
bdiag(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3)
```

And to do the whole directory (thanks to @user20650 in the comments) :

```
bdiag(lapply(dir(), function(x){as.matrix(read.table(x))}))
```

Comment: Okay this looks like a solid solution; however, I have several hundred text files so would I go about using this without inputting each text file manually?

Comment: @costebk08: The task of automating reading from directories with large numbers of files has been asked and answered repeatedly on SO. Please do some searching, and if you fail, then post the search terms you used as an edit to your question, and someone may suggest better strategies.

Comment: @BondedDust I have tried the following: `> megamatrix <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dir(), function(x) bdiag(as.matrix(read.table(x)))))` and am getting the following error:
`Error: Matrices must have same number of columns in rbind2(..1, r)`  The matrices have a different amount of columns so I am a bit stuck.

Comment: @user20650 I think you need an as.matrix : `bdiag(lapply(dir(), function(x){as.matrix(read.table(x))}))`

Comment: @user20650 I tried that and it yielded the following: `Error in as(x, "CsparseMatrix") : 
  no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “CsparseMatrix”` So then I tried:
`bdiag(lapply(dir(), as.matrix(read.table)))`  which yielded:
`Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`